# how DbContext.AttachRange() works in this scenario

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

I saw a book with some code like this:

```
public class Order 
{
   public int OrderID { get; set; }
   public ICollection<CartLine> Lines { get; set; }
   ...
}

public class CartLine
{
   public int CartLineID { get; set; }
   public Product Product { get; set; }
   public int Quantity { get; set; }
}

//Product class is just a normal class that has properties such as ProductID, Name etc
```

and in the order repository, there is a SaveOrder method:

```
public void SaveOrder(Order order)
{
   context.AttachRange(order.Lines.Select(l => l.Product));
   if (order.OrderID == 0)
   {
       context.Orders.Add(order);
   }
   context.SaveChanges();
}
```

and the book says:

**when store an Order object in the database. When the user’s cart data is deserialized from the session store, the JSON package creates new objects that are not known to
Entity Framework Core, which then tries to write all the objects into the database. For the Product objects, this means that Entity Framework Core tries to write objects that have already been stored, which causes an error. To avoid this problem, I notify Entity Framework Core that the objects exist and shouldn’t be stored in the database unless they are modified**

I'm confused, and have two questions:

Q1-why writing objects that have already been stored will cause an error, in the point of view of underlying database, it's just an update SQL statement that modify all columns to their current values?I know it does unnecessary works by changing nothing and rewrite everything, but it shouldn't throw any error in database level?

Q2-why we don't do the same thing to `CartLine` as:

```
context.AttachRange(order.Lines.Select(l => l.Product));
context.AttachRange(order.Lines);
```

to prevent `CartLine` objects stored in the database just as the way we do it to `Product` object?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay, so this is gonna be a long one:

**1st Question:**

In Entity Framework (core or "old" 6), there's this concept of "Change tracking". The `DbContext` class is capable of tracking all the changes you made to your data, and then applying it in the DB via SQL statements (INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE). To understand why it throws an error in your case, you first need to understand how the `DbContext` / change tracking actually works. Let's take your example:

```
public void SaveOrder(Order order)
{
   context.AttachRange(order.Lines.Select(l => l.Product));
   if (order.OrderID == 0)
   {
       context.Orders.Add(order);
   }
   context.SaveChanges();
}
```

In this method, you receive an `Order` instance which contains `Lines` and `Products`. Let's assume that this method was called from some web application, meaning you **didn't load the Order entity from the DB.** This is what's know as the [Disconected Scenario](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/disconnected-entities)

It's "disconnected" in the sense that your `DbContext` is not aware of their existence. When you do `context.AttachRange` you are literally telling EF: **I'm in control here, and I'm 100% sure these entities already exist in the DB. Please be aware of them for now on!**,

Let's use your code again: Imagine that it's a new `Order` (so it will enter your if there) and you remove the `context.AttachRange` part of the code. As soon as the code reaches the `Add` and `SaveChanges` these things will happen internally in the `DbContext`:

1. The `DetectChanges` method will be called
2. It will try to find all the entities `Order, Lines and Products` in its current graph
3. If it doesn't find them, they will be added to the "pending changes" as a **new records to be inserted**

Then you continue and call `SaveChanges` and it will fail as the book tells you. Why? Imagine that the `Products` selected were:

```
Id: 1, "Macbook Pro"
Id: 2, "Office Chair"
```

When the `DbContext` looked at the entities and didn't know about them, it added them to the pending changes with a state of `Added`. When you call `SaveChanges`, it issues the `INSERT` statements for these products based on their current state in the model. Since Id's `1 and 2` already exists in the database, the operation failed, with a Primary Key violation.

That's why you have to call `Attach` (or `AttachRange`) in this case. This effectively tells EF that the entities exist in the DB, and it should not try to insert them again. They will be added to the context with a state of `Unchanged`. `Attach` is often used in these cases where you didn't load the entities from the `dbContext` before.

**2nd question:**

This is hard for me to access because I don't know the context/model at that level, but here's my guess:

You don't need to do that with the `Cartline` because with every order, you probably want to insert new `Order line`. Think like buying stuff at Amazon. You put the products in the cart and it will generate an `Order`, then `Order Lines`, things that compose that order.

If you were then to update an existing order and add more items to it, then you would run into the same issue. You would have to load the existing `CartLines` prior to saving them in the db, or call `Attach` as you did here.

Hope it's a little bit clearer. I have answered a similar question where I gave more details, so maybe reading that also helps more:
[How does EF Core Modified Entity State behave?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54274166/how-does-ef-core-modified-entity-state-behave/55811226#55811226)

Comment: Thank for your concise answer. Now I understand Q1. So for Q2, your guess is correct, a new Order line needs to be inserted into database for every order, but since newly created products' ids are 0 , so can't  EF be a little bit smarter so when encounter objects which id > 0, it know users are trying to modify objects that does exist in the database, therefore we can get rid of Attach (or AttachRange)?

Comment: Yes, there is a way to do it without the Attach. I didn't go further on it to avoid overcomplicating the answer since now this is a new question :). Usually, if the entities have auto-generated keys (id is auto increment for example), only setting the ids will let EF know it is an UPDATE. But.. it will consider any other thing set on the entity. You can read this, to understand how all this works in more detail: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/disconnected-entities#mix-of-new-and-existing-entities

Comment: Part of the problem is the call to `Add`. It will mark then to be added, so the PK conflict. When you have a mix of insert/update (new order, but existing products), you can use `Update` instead and EF will figure it out which ones need to insert, based on the PK values. Again, this only works if the Id type is an autogenerated value.