# Temporal Tables and EF Core: The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, temporal-tables

I have an ASP.NET Core 7 app using EF Core 7.

My classes:

```
public class ApiUser : IdentityUser
{
    ...
    public virtual List<UserImage> Images { get; set; } = new();
}

public class UserImage : UdbObject
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey(nameof(User))]
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public virtual ApiUser User { get; set; }
    ...
    public virtual UserImageStat Stat { get; set; }
}

[PrimaryKey(nameof(UserImageId))]
public class UserImageStat
{
    [ForeignKey(nameof(Image))]
    public Guid UserImageId { get; set; }
    public virtual UserImage Image { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

My endpoint:

```
[HttpPut]
[Route("rollback")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Rollback(
    [FromQuery] string userId,
    [FromQuery] DateTime timeOfEdit)
{
    //Get historical user
    var historicalUser = await _context.Users
        .TemporalAsOf(timeOfEdit)
        .Where(x => x.Id == userId)
        .Include(e => e.Images).ThenInclude(img => img.Stat)
        .AsNoTracking()
        .FirstOrDefaultAsync();

    // Get current user
    var currentStateUser = await _context.Users
        .Where(x => x.Id == userId)
        .Include(e => e.Images).ThenInclude(img => img.Stat)
        .Include(e => e.Stat)
        .FirstOrDefaultAsync();

    if (historicalUser is null || currentStateUser is null)
        return BadRequest();

    // map historical to current
    _userMapper.Map_HistoricalUser_To_CurrentUserAsync<PropertyInfo>(historicalUser, currentStateUser);

    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    return NoContent();
}
```

My dumbed-down mapper:

```
public void Map_HistoricalUser_To_CurrentUserAsync<T>(
    ApiUser historicalUser,
    ApiUser currentUser) where T : PropertyInfo
{
    PropertyInfo[] properties = typeof(ApiUser).GetProperties();

    foreach (T property in properties)
    {
        if (property.Name != "Id")
        {
            object value = property.GetValue(historicalUser);
            property.SetValue(currentUser, value);
        }
    }
}
```

In my scenario, when executing `Rollback`, initially `historicalUser.Images` has one member, and `currentStateUser.Images` has zero members.

After the mapper `Map_HistoricalUser_To_CurrentUserAsync` is executed within the endpoint, `currentStateUser.Images` now has the member (taken from `historicalUser.Images`, including the `UserImageStat` property).

Upon calling `await _context.SaveChangesAsync();` I am getting the following error:

> The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_UserImageStats_UserImages_UserImageId". The conflict occurred in database "myDb", table "dbo.UserImages", column 'Id'.

I thought that when you call `SaveChangesAsync`, all entities are ordered from an internal order in the method `ProduceDynamicCommands` which handles insertion order (i.e. if you add A and B and A depends on B, then B will be inserted before A)...

**Edit** - if I modify `Map_HistoricalUser_To_CurrentUserAsync` and explicitly insert the Images into `currentUser` and then reset the `Id` values like I do below, it works. Why is this happening? Would I need to modify how I define the model to be able to insert the 'original' Ids taken from the temporal Historical tables?

```
public void Map_HistoricalUser_To_CurrentUserAsync<T>(
        ApiUser historicalUser,
        ApiUser currentUser) where T : PropertyInfo
    {
        PropertyInfo[] properties = typeof(ApiUser).GetProperties();
    
        foreach (T property in properties)
        {
            if (property.Name != "Id" &&
                property.Name != "Images")
            {
                object value = property.GetValue(historicalUser);
                property.SetValue(currentUser, value);
            }
        }

        currentUser.Images.AddRange(historicalUser.Images);
        currentUser.Images.First().Id = Guid.Empty;
        currentUser.Images.First().Stat.UserImageId = Guid.Empty;
    }
```

Comment: Could it be that you're trying to restore image that no longer exist in the db?

Comment: No, `[dbo].[UserImages]` is a temporal table (as is `[dbo].[UserImageStats]`), and I am able to load the record in question from their corresponding historical tables. I am getting the error upon saving `currentStateUser` with the restored `UserImage` and `UserImage.UserImageStat` within `currentStateUser.Images`. It's almost like the DB engine is trying to insert the `UserImageStat` record before it is inserting the `UserImage` record, but as I mentioned in my original post, I thought the order of insertion was automatically handled behind the scenes.

Comment: This looks like EF. If so and you're modifying the entity, you have to detect the changes. Change the entity state for currentStateUser to modified: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54274166/how-does-ef-core-modified-entity-state-behave