# Entity Framework returns null after update the entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am new in Entity Framework and trying to update entity and return it with its relations. First of all EF doesn't return the entity with its relations. It only returns itself, so i decided to first update the entity and then get the entity with its relations. But this time when I call `GetSingle` method, I got that entity null.

Here is the entity class:

```
public class Seller : BaseEntity
{
    public string UserId { get; set; } = String.Empty;
    public ApplicationUser? User { get; set; }

    public string? Speciality { get; set; } = String.Empty;
    public string? Industry { get; set; } = String.Empty;
    public string? Graduation { get; set; } = String.Empty;

    public Guid? SellerImageId { get; set; }
    public Image? SellerImage { get; set; }

    public Guid? SellerMainCategoryId { get; set; }
    public Category? SellerMainCategory { get; set; }

    public string SellerBio { get; set; } = String.Empty;
    
    [NotMapped] 
    public IFormFile? ImageFile { get; set; }

    //Navigation
    public SellerCompany? SellerCompany { get; set; }
    
    public List<SellerBankInfo>? SellerBankInfos { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the controller method:

```
[HttpPut]
[Route("update")]
public async Task<ResponseData> Update([FromBody] UpdateSellerDto updateSellerDto)
{
    var sellerEntity = _mapper.Map<Seller>(updateSellerDto);

    sellerEntity = await _sellerService.UpdateSellerAsync(sellerEntity);

    if (sellerEntity is null)
    {
        return Execute(UnSuccessRequest, () =>
            {
                return "Error on Update";
            });
    }

    var updatedSeller = await _sellerService.GetSingleSeller(Guid.Parse(updateSellerDto.Id));
    var sellerResponse = _mapper.Map<GetSingleSellerResponseDto>(updatedSeller);

    return Execute(SuccessRequest, () =>
        {
            return sellerResponse;
        });
}
```

Here is the service method for update (this method updates but returns only the entity not the entity with its relations like 'SellerMainCategory'):

```
public async Task<Seller> UpdateSellerAsync(Seller seller)
{
    var updateResult = _context.Sellers.Update(seller);
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

    return updateResult.Entity;
}
```

And here is the single get method in the service; this works when I only call this method, but returns null when I call it after update:

```
public async Task<Seller?> GetSingleSeller(Guid userId) 
{
    var seller = await _context.Sellers
                               .Include(c => c.User)
                               .Include(x => x.SellerMainCategory)
                               .FirstOrDefaultAsync(s => s.UserId == userId.ToString());

    return seller;
}
```

I just couldn't understand the workflow of EF.

Comment: You need to set the entity state to modified before SaveChangesAsync(): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54274166/how-does-ef-core-modified-entity-state-behave

Comment: `public IFormFile? ImageFile { get; set; }` <-- Ugh. You **should not** be re-using EF entity classes as two-way ASP.NET ViewModels or as DTOs. You will run into further problems if you keep doing this.

Comment: Also, your application has a gaping security vulnerability to overposting attacks.

Comment: @Dai I should seperate ImageFile from entity and use it only in DTO right? But i don't know what is gaping security vulnerability to overposting attacks and how to prevent from that. Thanks for the warnings.

Comment: @mehmetserif _anyone_ can hand-craft a `POST` request to your service that overwrites any FK in your entity-class-reused-as-a-DTO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reproduced your issue and try several methods.

Finally I find that when you use `Include()` after `Update()`, You need to change your code from:

```
_context.sellers.Include(x => x.category).FirstOrDefault(x=>x.Id==xxxx);
```

to:

```
_context.sellers.Include(x => x.category).Where(x => x.Id == xxx).AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefault();
```

Hope it can help you solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You should set the entity state to modified before updating the object(SaveChangesAsync).

Comment: Yes, this way it's worked. But one more thing to know, there is a relationship between Seller and Category, if i don't call getSingleSeller function, EntityEntry doesn't contain the related object after updating. Do you know why and is there a solution for that?

Comment: If You update an entity using **Update** method in dbContext, EF execute some SQL code containing one or more UPDATE rows and nothing else. So, if You want some value of a property that You didn't update (ex. a navigation property), You must read it form its table.